# (Excel Userform) Check if all checkboxes in a Userform are checked

Tags: vba, excel

Never tried UserForm checkboxes before so I don't even know how to point to the Checkboxes in a Userform.

This is what I have at the moment....and I know, I know, it is completely wrong. Please help?

```
Private Sub Step1_Confirm_Click()
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim Done As Boolean

    For i = 1 To 4
        If Step1_(i).value = True Then
            Done = True
        End If
    Next i

    If Not Done = True Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure you have done all"
    End If

End Sub
```

Basically I have:

1. A Userform called `IOSP_Acc_R_Approval_Step1`
2. 4 checkboxes called `Step1_1`; `Step1_2`; `Step1_3`; `Step1_4`
3. A button called `Step1_Confirm`
4. I want the button to show Error, if not all checkboxes are checked - meaning that all checkboxes have to be checked....(in case my English is too bad to convey my meaning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by:

- assume that all checkboxes are checked by setting a flag to `True`
- iterate the checkboxes and if one is not checked set the flag to `False` and exit
- at the end of the loop, if all checkboxes were checked then the flag is still `True`

You can refer to the checkboxes dynamically by using the `Me.Controls` collection and pass in the name of the checkbox like `"Step1_" & i`.

Example code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Step1_Confirm_Click()

    Dim i As Long '<-- use Long, not Byte
    Dim blnResult As Boolean

    ' set a flag to assume that it is true that all checkboxes are checked
    blnResult = True

    ' get the value of each check box
    For i = 1 To 4
        If Me.Controls("Step1_" & i).Value = False Then
            blnResult = False
            Exit For '<-- skip loop if at least one box not checked
        End If
    Next i

    ' check the value of the flag
    If blnResult = False Then
        MsgBox "Please make sure you have done all"
    Else
        ' all boxes checked ...
        MsgBox "All checked"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I've learned something new again - it's .Controls!

And how could I forget about Exit For.....thanks~~~

Comment: You'll get errors if there's other types of controls on the userform.

Answer (score 4):

Try the code below (explanations inside the code as comments):

```
Private Sub Step1_Confirm_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim Ctrl As Control

' loop through all user_form control
For Each Ctrl In IOSP_Acc_R_Approval.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then ' check if control type is Check-Box
        If Ctrl.Value = True Then ' check if check-box is checked
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl

If i < 4 Then ' not all 4 check-boxes are checked
    MsgBox "Please make sure you have done all"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I later thought about this myself and I actually made it work. And of course your solution worked too! Thanks

Comment: @herman925 your;e welcome, since you accepted Robi';s answer, you can upvote mine (if it helped you)

Comment: I upvoted you just for using `TypeName` and not `TypeOf` ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes it did! It broadened by scope of experience to do something else similar in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
    Done=true 
For i = 1 To 4
            Done = Done*Step1_(i).value
        Next i
if done `then`
msgbox "All checkboxes are checked"
end if
```