# Create a file from A VB FORM with checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm trying to create a Excel Macro. Within the Macro I have created a Form with several check boxes to define what I want the output to be. Is there a way to write a Sub to search all of the form for the "checked" ones and output the names to a file? Any information would be grateful, thanks!

Zookeeper

Comment: The `.Value` property of `CheckBox1` etc (or whatever you call the controls) will return `True` if checked, `False` if not checked, and `Null` if in the triple-state position.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have that part figured out but wanted to see if there was a way to loop or use a command that would search the form for all the check marks. Then write that to a file.  I would hate to write all 70 of the .values for each checkbox.

Comment: OK - check out [How to loop through CheckBoxes on UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24221346/6535336) and [(Excel Userform) Check if all checkboxes in a Userform are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44535704/6535336) and several others that can be found with a google of `site:stackoverflow.com excel vba loop through all checkboxes on a form` - that should get you there.

Comment: Thank you all I have found the answer. :) I appreciate your help. Now on to a bigger issue. Thanks!